# How to resolve error with StoreConfig, CalculatorType, and CalculatorConfig when using xtype: rallychart

Tags: javascript, charts, rally

I am working to resolve a problem with a Rally App, using the Rally-App-Builder. The point of this app is to graph some data on a chart for easy reading. The chart I am using is of `xtype: rallychart`.

When this app is put on a rally page it works with no issues, but once I try to build and run the app using the rally app builder I run into the following issues:

- `Missing required configuration field: storeConfig`
- `Missing required configuration field: calculatorType`
- `Missing required configuration field: calculatorConfig`
- `Your request requires access to a workspace or project for which you do not have permission. Contact your subscription administrator to request permission.`

I get these errors in that specific order, one at a time. These errors do not show up in the rally app builder, they only show up once I try to run the app. These error messages will show up where the chart should be, and the only error that says anything in the console is the last one listed above. The error related to permissions displays the following error in the output console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

The first three errors are solved when I add the following lines to the chart declaration:

```
storeConfig: {
    find: {
        _TypeHierarchy: "HierarchicalRequirement" //This means User Story?
    }   
},
calculatorType: 'Rally.data.lookback.calculator.TimeSeriesCalculator',
calculatorConfig: {} ,
```

My guess is that the final, permissions related error message is misleading, and that the error is somewhere within the `storeConfig`,`calculatorType`,or `calculatorConfig` properties.

The part that confuses me is the fact that none of the properties listed above are needed for the app to function properly on the rally website, but they are needed for some reason when running using the Rally-App-Builder.

Help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated, and if more information is needed to successfully do so, please let me know. I will be attaching the entire chart declaration below:

```
this.chart = this.down('#chart').add( {
    storeConfig: {
        find: {
            _TypeHierarchy: "HierarchicalRequirement" //This means User Story?
        }   
    },
    calculatorType: 'Rally.data.lookback.calculator.TimeSeriesCalculator',
    calculatorConfig: {} ,
    xtype: 'rallychart',
    height: 400,
    series: [
    {
        type: 'line',
        dataIndex: 'CycleTime',
        name: 'Story Cycle Time',
        visible: true
    },
    {
        type: 'line',
        dataIndex: 'LeadTime',
        name: 'Story Lead Time',
        visible: false
    },

        ],
    store: snapshotStore,
    chartConfig: {
        chart: {
            marginRight: 10,
            marginBottom: 100,
            zoomType: 'xy',
            animation: {
                duration: 1500,
                easing: 'swing'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Story Cycle Time Control Chart',
            align: 'center'
        },
        xAxis: [
        {
            categories: myXAxis,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
            ],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Time (days)'
            },
            plotLines: [
            {
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            },
            {
                value: meanCycleTime,
                width: 2,
                color: '#808080',
                label: {
                    text: 'Mean Cycle Time',
                    align: 'left'
                }
            },
            {
                value: 14,
                width: 2,
                color: '#0083ff',
            label: {
                    text: 'Sprint Duration',
                    align: 'center'
                }
            },
            {
                value: 56,
                width: 2,
                color: '#0083ff',
                label: {
                text: 'PSI Duration',
                align: 'center'
                }
            },
            {
                value: UCLCycleTime,
                width: 1,
                color: '#FF0000',
                label: {
                    text: 'UCL',
                    align: 'left'
                }
            }
                ]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                color: '#F00'
            },
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 3000,
                    easing: 'swing'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check out this option: https://rally1.rallydev.com/docs/en-us/saas/apps/2.1/doc/index.html#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore-cfg-removeUnauthorizedSnapshots

With the SnapshotStore, this sort of problem occurs when the project you are working in has artefacts that have been moved into that project from some other project you do not have permissions for. The snapshotstore respects the permissions that were present at the time the change to the artefact was made.

A simple test to see if it is a permission problem is to get a workspace admin to run the same app. If it then works, then it is definitely a permissions issue.